# expression for mysql 5.7 virtual column

Tags: mysql, expression, formula, mysql-5.7

mysql table has columns order-id, order-item-id. Need to create a expression for generated column (new feature on 5.7) please have a look at the image for v virtual generated column look at the image for easy understanding. Tablename is daily-orders

[image]

Comment: Do you need to simulate an order-id dependent auto-increment field? If yes, can you confirm that it should follow order-item-id in ascending order? Also, can you pls share with us what you have attempted so far?

Comment: need to have similar to countif of excel,  for order id ( group by & tell how many orders are in that group) as it is a single line expression. I don't know which reserved function should be used to get this done.

Comment: The generated column above is not the result of a countif() in excel. Your sample output contradicts you comment. Pls update your sample output or explain it better in a comment. Either way, I'm not sure that you can use generated columns for this purpose because determining this number would require scanning the entire table (i.e subquery), which is not allowed in generated columns. You may have to implement this feature in a view using subquery, rather than as a generated column.

Comment: @shadow. Thanks for your pointout, have  updated the image please look into table can this be achieved in generated column or will need to create a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to limitations on [generated columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html), you cannot create an expression that contains subqueries:

> Subqueries, parameters, variables, stored functions, and user-defined functions are not permitted.

Since you would like to obtain information on data in multiple records, you have to use a subquery and that is not permitted. However, you can create a view instead of a generated column that contains this additional data. The following sql statement could form the core of such view:

```
select d1.*, d2.NumberOfItems
from dailyorders d1
inner join (select orderid, count(*) as NumberOfItems from dailyorders group by orderid) d2
on d1.orderid=d2.orderid
```